# How can I make Steam use Nvidia Graphics on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: nvidia, steam, 21.10

My question is in the title.

I just want Steam and games launched by Steam to use proper acceleration. I expected this to work out of the box on a fresh Ubuntu 21.10 installation, but apparently, it doesn't. I am using the Nvidia 510 driver and nvidia-prime is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it works. Not sure what I did.

Anyway, [here is the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006857/638583) to my question:

> Launch Steam from terminal using DRI_PRIME=1 steam. Now every game you
> launch from Steam will use the AMD GPU.
>
> Alternatively, if you are using GNOME, you can right-click the steam
> icon then choose "Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card".

Answer (score 1):

Add `prime-run %command%` to the launch options of your game.

In my experience, all games using DXVK (non-native games) run on the dedicated Nvidia GPU by default, so not necessary to add it for those.